# how to give the test size in stratified kfold sampling in python?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

Using sklearn , I want to have 3 splits (i.e. n_splits = 3)in the sample dataset and have a Train/Test ratio as 70:30. I'm able split the set into 3 folds but not able to define the test size (similar to train_test_split method).Is there a way to do define test sample size in StratifiedKFold ?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold as SKF
skf = SKF(n_splits=3)
skf.get_n_splits(X, y)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
# Loops over 3 iterations to have Train test stratified split
     X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`StratifiedKFold` does by definition a K-fold split. This is, the iterator returned will yield (`K-1`) sets for training while `1` set for testing. `K` is controlled by `n_splits`, and thus, it does create groups of `n_samples/K`, and use all combinations of `K-1` for training/testing. Refer to wikipedia or google [K-fold cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation) for more info about it.

In short, the size of the test set will be `1/K` (i.e. `1/n_splits`), so you can tune that parameter to control the test size (e.g. `n_splits=3` will have test split of size `1/3 = 33%` of your data). However, `StratifiedKFold` will iterate over `K` groups of `K-1`, and might not be what you want.

Having said that, you might be interested in [StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit), which returns just configurable number of splits and train/test ratio. If you just want a single split, you can tune `n_splits=1` and yet keep `test_size=0.3` (or whatever ratio you want).