# Random stratified split of dataframe into multiple samples in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to split a pandas dataframe into multiple, mutually exclusive samples (of different length) stratified on a variable?

My current approach is to use train_test_split from sci-kit learn multiple times for each sample, but feels very inefficient.

```
cell_to_split, cell_1 = train_test_split(data, test_size=50, stratify=strat_variable)
cell_to_split, cell_2 = train_test_split(cell_to_split, test_size=60, stratify=strat_variable)
cell_to_split, cell_3 = train_test_split(cell_to_split, test_size=40, stratify=strat_variable)

# strat_variable here is a string variable in data or cell_to_split i'm using for random stratified sampling
```

This lets me get 3 samples from the dataset with specified size (number of rows) in each, balanced for representativeness on my strat_variable, but isn't too efficient, and I'd ideally like the number of samples (set as 3 here) to be dynamic.

Comment: Try Stratified K-Folds cross-validator https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html

Comment: Thanks for the qiuck reply. I may have cases where I need the samples to be different sizes though, don't see a way to specify that in Strat Fold. Also updated my question to make that clearer

Comment: then try Stratified ShuffleSplit cross-validator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500915/how-to-give-the-test-size-in-stratified-kfold-sampling-in-python

Comment: This answer is closest to your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501510/6660373